Unable to hide/unhide second field based on picklist inputfield value
Visualforce Page:
<apex:outputPanel id="Complaint" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Complaint" columns="2" id="Complaints" rendered="{!RenderComplaintsFields}">
          <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Line_of_Business__c}" required="true" id="lineOfBusinessId">
            <apex:actionSupport status="submitStatus" event="onchange" reRender="claimId"/>
          </apex:inputField>
          <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Claim_Ref_Number__c}" rendered="{!RenderClaimRef}" id="claimId"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:outputPanel>

Apex:
public Boolean getRenderClaimRef(){
        if(theCase.Line_of_Business__c!='General Insurance' && Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.Claim_Ref_Number__c.isAccessible()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Only rendered while page loading not at every time when I changed the first field picklist value.
I tried with JavaScript but it shows the field values as null, is this due to outputpanel?
Please suggest me to check/rendered when the value changes and second field should hide/unhide.

Your apex:actionSupport event is misspelled. event="onchnage" should be onchange

@MorganMarchese, thanks I just changed the spelling but even though it's not working

@MorganMarchese, just updated the code please check

The event attribute should be onchange instead of onchnage. Aslo, Make sure the reRender attribute correctly targets the component that needs to be updated.
VF Page:
<apex:outputPanel id="Complaint">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Complaint" columns="2" id="Complaints" rendered="{!RenderComplaintsFields}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Line_of_Business__c}" required="true" id="lineOfBusinessId">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="claimId" />
                </apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Claim_Ref_Number__c}" rendered="{!RenderClaimRef}" id="claimId" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>

Apex:
public Boolean getRenderClaimRef() {
        if (theCase.Line_of_Business__c != 'General Insurance' && 
        Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.Claim_Ref_Number__c.isAccessible()) {
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}


except 'onchange' remaining everything is correct and after giving the correct spelling also it not working

@PavanKumarH are you sure !RenderClaimRef is returning true on reRender? Have you debugged the controller?

@MorganMarchese, yes the method working correctly
